# Making VBA Form TextBox accept Numbers only (including +, - and .)

Tags: vba, excel

I have simple textBox and I want to validate its input including "+" , "-"  and "." here is what I have tried

```
Private Sub DisplayValue_TextBox_Change()
If Not IsNumeric(DisplayValue_TextBox.Value) Then
               MsgBox "Only numbers allowed"

      End If
End Sub
```

But this only accepts numbers 0-9 no negative, positive value or float value..

Comment: because `Textbox_Change()` fires everytime there is a new character entered in the textbox. You should consider using a different event like `_Exit()` or `_AfterUpdate()` to validate the value on the loss of focus for example

Comment: `_Change()` event is good when user form requires only positive integers input. At first I used it however it's a bit annoying because it detects *every* change - including pressing backspace.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Further to my comment:

Consider a sample Userform1 with a Textbox1 and a CommandButton1

[image]

when you enter anything in the `TextBox1` the change event fires - ie. typing one character fires the `Change()` event and passes the current value so even when you type in the negative sign your current logic fails.

What you need is to use another event like `_AfterUpdate()` or `_Exit()` with an amphasis on the second one because your can cancel the event :)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
        MsgBox "only numbers allowed"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You can find events here:

[image]

Answer (score 23):

use the KeyPress event, and discard any non-numeric entry:

```
Private Sub txtShift1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
Debug.Print KeyAscii
If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
    Debug.Print "number"
Else
    Debug.Print "other"
    KeyAscii = 0
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 11):

Having relied up till now on string parsing to do this job, I'm glad I decided to check and see how other people do it and found this Q.

I've refined Ruben Alvarez's excellent answer.  The below will allow numerical entries only, and only one decimal point.

```
Private Sub txtShift1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 46
            If InStr(1, txtShift1, ".") > 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case 48 To 57
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
    End Select

End Sub
```

This could be further refined to allow only a single "+", "-" etc. as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I use this. It will allow only numbers with decimals.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: vbKeyLeft allows % to be included, while vbKeyRight allows '. Anyway, it appears that in my userforms the arrowkeys work even if I don't explicitly allow them, apparently not all keypresses are keypresses, and the numbering of the vbKeys does not correspond strictly to the keys' ascii numbers

Comment: yes you are right. %,&,(,)  get inserted. I am sure you can tackle them by capturing the shift key.

Answer (score 1):

Im using that:

```
Private Sub txtGiaNet_Change()
    If IsNumeric(txtGiaNet.Value) Then
        //if number do sth
    Else
        //if not, delete this character
        txtGiaNet.Value = Left(txtGiaNet.Value, Len(txtGiaNet.Value) - 1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That will only work if the insertion point is currently at the end of the string.  Better to kill the input before it reaches the control's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
    Dim N As Boolean
    N = True
    Do While N
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Then
            TextBox1.Value = Left(TextBox1.Value, Len(TextBox1.Value) - 1)
        Else
            N = False
        End If
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TbCout_D_Edlp_Change()

Dim NotNumeric As Boolean

Dim TempValue As String

     If Not IsNumeric(TbCout_D_Edlp.Value) Then
 
        If TbCout_D_Edlp.Value <> "" Then
        
              NotNumeric = True
              
              MsgBox "Only numbers allowed"
              
              TempValue = Left(Me.TbCout_D_Edlp.Value, Len(Me.TbCout_D_Edlp.Value) - 1)
              
              While NotNumeric = True And TempValue <> ""
              
                   If Not IsNumeric(TempValue) Then
              
                        TempValue = Left(TempValue, Len(TempValue) - 1)
                        
                   
                   Else
                        
                        NotNumeric = False
                        
                   End If
        
              Wend
              
              Me.TbCout_D_Edlp.Value = TempValue
                
        End If
        
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This code will give you the option of having a error message without repeating itselft if the person copy paste a value that is not numeric and It gives you also the flexibility to have decimal. This code will also remove the last entry when it's a non numeric value and will not be displayed in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I was fine with the OPs limitations on the type of values accepted but wasn't fine with the msgbox arriving at inappropriate times (such as when Backspace was used).  To resolve that, I created a calculated field in the worksheet ("Value_AnyGood") that used the ISNUMBER function on the entered data. I then tested that for "True" on any event that left the UF where the data was entered. That resulted in a process that caught any non-numeric entries but didn't pop up a message for legitimate editing efforts. If the value was False, it lets the user know and then ends the routine with the current UF displayed.

Comment: Just clarify what the acronym "FWIW" means.