# User can copy, paste, delete, backspace etc. but cannot enter letters (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code for textbox where I want to let the user input a numeric value, copy, delete etc. but not enter a letter. What I have below will show a msgbox for backspace, which isn't right.

I'd like the msgbox to appear instantly as a letter is typed.

Any tips?

```
Private Sub fCYE_Change()
If Not IsNumeric(fCYE.Value) Then
               msgbox "Only numbers allowed"

      End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not Data Validation? Data tab -> Data Tools -> Data Validation [Excel 2016]

Comment: @ppz is correct. You are trying to program something that is already included in Excel as a built-in feature. Also, data validation will be much faster than running some code to do the same thing.

Comment: This is on a userform. Sorry, should've clarified this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making VBA Form TextBox accept Numbers only (including +, - and .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and)

Comment: That's the one I had used as template to write this code. The issue with the one you refer is that msgbox is only displayed once you click out of the textbox (or hit tab), I'd rather msgbox appear as soon as a letter is typed.

Answer (score 0):

From [Making VBA Form TextBox accept Numbers only (including +, - and .)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and)

```
Private Sub txtShift1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 46
            If InStr(1, txtShift1, ".") > 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case 48 To 57
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0  '** AJD Comment/addition: Change this line, see below.
    End Select
End Sub
```

Trivial exercise for you to add extra cases for characters you want to allow.

### Your specific answer

Instead of just `KeyAscii = 0` you can have

```
KeyAscii = 0
MsgBox(...)
```

You also have the option of doing some additional cleaning up before issuing the `MsgBox` command.

You can also get a bit more sophisticated. The following code is an example only:

```
    KeyAscii = 0
    result = MsgBox(...)
    If result = vbCancel then Me.Hide 'effectively closing the form as well.
```