# Number only text box not working on one of two text boxes in a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I have two text boxes on a userform that I would like to be numeric only. The first one works fine based on this( [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and)), however the second one, which I have implemented in exactly the same way as the first is not working, and I don't know why. Any idea why?

The first textbox is call TextBoxMainVal
The second is called perHour
Code:

```
'If the Main Value box does not recieve a number send a message to make them change it
Private Sub TextBoxMainVal_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  If TextBoxMainVal.Value = "" Then
  ElseIf Not IsNumeric(TextBoxMainVal.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Enter numbers only"
    Cancel = True
    TextBoxMainVal.Value = vbNullString
  End If
End Sub

'I DONT KNOW WHY THIS ONE ISNT WORKING!
Private Sub perHour_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  If perHour.Value = "" Then
  ElseIf Not IsNumeric(perHour.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Enter numbers only"
    Cancel = True
    perHour.Value = vbNullString
  End If
End Sub
```

I thought there could be a naming error conflict, so I changed the textbox name, but that did not resolve it.
I cant understand why it is not working. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Why not handle `KeyDown` instead, and *prevent* invalid input from being entered in the first place?

Comment: The method worked for my first text box, so I didn't see a need to change it. Confusing me as to why the second one is not working

Comment: Can you edit to actually define "not working"? Is it blowing up? It's an `Exit` handler, so it won't run until the control loses focus. Is it running if you tab out of the textbox? If you place a breakpoint (F9), is it hit?

Comment: Also, if you're inside the handler, does the top-left code pane dropdown say "perHour" or "(General)"?

Comment: What do you mean to define as 'not working'?  Regarding placing a breakpoint, I did so, and no, it is not hitting. Good catch there. Why might this be the case? The top left does say 'perHour'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested why this may happen there is an answer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ec70204-02bc-4f01-bbb6-205af1fa4684/exit-event-for-textbox-included-in-a-frame?forum=isvvba). The reason, it appears, the textbox exit handler is not occurring is because it is outside of a frame. For the exit handler to work you need to stay inside the frame.