# How to show balance or any figure from sheet to user form?

Tags: excel, userform

I need to have balance from a sheet shown onto the user form. If anybody can help in doing so I'd appreciate it very much.

Do I use listbox for the numbers to be displayed? 
Balance is auto updated in the sheet so the last row or last updated number should show on user form.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers.

The code in Userform1 is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: TLDR; please limit your question to show the relevant information **only**. This reads like a high school math problem attempting to confuse the test taker by bombarding with extra info. I doubt all of the above info is needed for populating a userform listbox from a range.

Comment: Also don't force your deadlines upon people, that comes across as rude very often.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Noted. I was trying to explain things to the best of my ability. Clearly failed. I will edit the question and I apologies if my question came on as rude. A bit of humor it was.and nothing more but many thanks for pointing out it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to show and how.

Assuming the value you need (what you call 'balance') is a value stored in the last filled in cell of column A and that you want to display in a textbox you could:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()        
    LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & 
Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'TextBox Store
TextBox.Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow, 1).Value

end sub
```

If you want to display this information in a label to provide additional info to the user you should enter a label, called for instance Label1 and add to your code something like:

```
Label1.Caption = "Balance is: " & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(LastRow,1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Lambik much appreciate it. The Column is G and the value which should display on user form is the last row of Column G. I understand some of the code which you provided, I will give it a try and if run into any issues I will update here. The Balance is the name of the field which I've given it. Simple, few rows add up minus one row and balance is calculated. Whatever the last value is it will be shown to the user on the user form. They can not edit it its just for reference that how much the telly is. I'm not allowed to pic or I would for better explanation.

Comment: Not part of this but O'well I suppose since you gave the code earlier probably you know already what I'm talking about. In other code can I restrict user form to only accept numeric values which goes in row 3, 4, 5 and 6? Right now it accepts all, admin fee can not be entered as hello or later lol it should be numeric value only.

Comment: check this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and

Comment: Thanks for that. I will read it in few mins once done with this balance. Your code disappeared which you gave a min ago....

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the code you need is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).row

'Text Label 1 should display
Label1.Caption = "Balance is: " & ws.Cells(LastRow,7).Value

end sub
```

Comment: OK let me quickly edit my question with the code which is already in Userform1 so I can give accurate information. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Got it, the page was not refreshed. Sorry!

Comment: I tried it but It gives runtime error 9. I added your code under the original code which is already in Userform1 did I missed anything or not doing it correctly?

Comment: please post your complete code so I can have a look at it.

Comment: OK will do that now.

Comment: Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

   'Text Label 1 should display
    Label1.Caption = "Balance is: " & ws.Cells(LastRow, 7).Value This is with your code from earlier. Original Userform1 code is the post, I edited the post to include it.

Comment: Sigh. Sorry still struggling with formatting. Many apologies.

Comment: OK I will delete this question because its all messed up, I will post a new one with clear code and it'll be easier then.