# How to verify 2 variables are Integer type?

Tags: excel, vba, types, integer

I would like to let user enter two integers (two text boxes)
While this condition is not satisfied, i want to let user fill again the text boxes.

Here is what I've tried but it's not the right answer:

```
Sub verif_type(n1, n2)


    If TypeName(n1) = "Integer" And TypeName(n2) = "Integer" Then
        MsgBox ("C'est bon !")

    Else
        MsgBox ("C'est pas bon, recommencez !")
        Unload UserForm1
        Call verif_type(n1, n2)
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you prompting the user for new values? At present, if the user passes an invalid value you end up stuck in a loop where you recursively call the verif_type function

Comment: You could prevent the user from entering text by only allowing numeric values in the textbox. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and)

Comment: The verification should happen within the user form.

Comment: `Integer` is in not `Double` or `Integer` as the 16-bit integer type. What about the 32-bit `Long` type?

Comment: I would recommed handling the `_KeyPress` to control the user input rather than post handling of data. @Storax has shared a good link which can help you with thta

Comment: @SiddharthRout when doing that, we need to find a workaround for pasting into the textbox. Otherwise some people will not like you :)

Comment: LOL. true that @Pᴇʜ Restricting paste in a TB is not very difficult. One can use `If (Shift And 2) And (KeyCode = Asc("V")) Then` in `TextBox1_KeyDown` to trap it. Similarly one will have to trap Shift+Insert as well :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes true, while blocking pasting is easy, it is a way more complicated if you want to allow pasting valid data only. I had this issue several times when trying to paste serial numbers where apps blocked pasting completely. That totally sucks if you cannot paste and have to type them and then you have to start over typing it completely again, just because you had one typo in a 16 digit apha numeric serial. That's why I don't like KeyDown limitations in boxes and I prefer validating by OK button. • In the end it depends on the kind of use of that textbox but should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a text box would most probably return a string every time. Thus, for an integer check, make sure that the number is numeric and has no `,` or `.` in it. To make sure it is a VBA integer, you may also see whether it is in the boundaries of one -32768 to 32767.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    verifType InputBox("Please enter value")

End Sub

Sub verifType(n1)

    If IsNumeric(n1) _
            And InStr(1, n1, ",") = 0 _
            And InStr(1, n1, ".") = 0 Then

        Debug.Print "Numeric!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not Numeric!"
        TestMe
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above is called through `TestMe()` and gets only one variable (easier to write than 2). If it is not `Integer` then it is called again. Follow some similar logic to build up your case.

Comment: `n1 Like "*[!0-9]*"` might be better. `IsNumeric` will return true if the string contains the currency symbol from the regional settings.

Comment: @Comintern - you are right. If you feel like it, please edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could check for the length of the string before and after conversion to a Long:

```
Function IsInteger(n1 As Variant)
    If IsNumeric(n1) Then IsInteger = Len(n1) = Len(CStr(CLng(n1)))
End Function
```

so your `UserForm1` button click event code could be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' change "CommandButton1" to your actual command button name
    If IsInteger(Me.TextBox1) And IsInteger(Me.TextBox2) Then
        MsgBox ("C'est bon !")
        Me.Hide
    Else
        MsgBox ("C'est pas bon, recommencez !")
    End If
End Sub
```

while your "main" calling code could be:

```
Sub main()

    ...

    With New UserForm1
        ...
        (possible code to pre-set UserForm1 controls to show to user)
        ...

        .Show

        ...
        (code to exploit UserForm1 controls values after user interaction)
        ...

    End With

    ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Using twice "=" in one line will make you hated in a lot of places. But this is the VBA tag, which noone cares about, so you are lucky.

Comment: @Vityata, I feel unlucky for getting no feedbacks but for useless matters

Comment: Feeling lucky or unlucky on Saturday night is your own choice.

Comment: @DisplayName You should declare the return of the function as boolean: `Function IsInteger(n1 As Variant) As Boolean` otherwise it will return an empty string if `n1` is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the contents of the textbox can be interpreted as a number using IsNumeric
Second, check that the value of those contents is equal to the rounded value of those contents

```
if IsNumeric(n1) then
       if val(n1) = floor(val(n1)) then
              ' number is good, take appropriate action
       else
              ' Inform user and take appropriate action
       end if
else 
       'Inform user and take appropriate action
end if
```

From experience, I would recommend placing the validity check inside the change event on the textbox, and feed back to the user using a textbox or label containing a status message.

Comment: Is `floor()` a VBA function? As to my knowledge it is s `WorksheetFunction` one. Moreover `Val` function can be misleading: try `?Val("1.2")` or `?Val("1,2")` in Immediate Window

Comment: The VBA function you're looking for is [`Fix`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions), not `floor`.

Comment: Yes, fix, or any rounding function.

Comment: So there it stays the Val() function issue

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls itself recursively if the inputted variables are not the right type. This will create an endless loop.

Logically, any verification function should return a simple "Yes" or "No". Either it is verified or it is not. This means returning a simple `Boolean` - which in turn means that it should be a `Function` instead of a `Sub`.

And ***always*** use `Option Explicit`.

```
Function verif_type(n1 as Variant, n2 as Variant) as Boolean
    If TypeName(n1) = "Integer" And TypeName(n2) = "Integer" Then
        verif_type = True
        'MsgBox ("C'est bon !")
    Else
        verif_type = False
        'MsgBox ("C'est pas bon, recommencez !")
        'Unload UserForm1
        'Call verif_type(n1, n2)
    End If
End Function
```

But that, in itself, can be further simplified as

```
Function verif_type(n1 as Variant, n2 as Variant) as Boolean
    verif_type = TypeName(n1) = "Integer" And TypeName(n2) = "Integer"
End Function
```

Now all your response logic is in your main code (I assume in your `UserForm`).

```
If verif_type(a,b) then
    ' Do something
Else
    ' Do something else
End If
```