# Issue with Maximum Value for Userform Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a maximum value for a textbook in a userform that pulls tables over from SQL. This userform links to SQL query in a separate part of the workbook.

In the userform, the user can specify in a textbox (`txtrownum`) how many rows they want to be returned. The maximum they can return is 100,000.

If it is more than 100,000, I have a `MsgBox` appear saying the max amount is 100,000 and the textbox value then autofills to 100,000.

That code works great and is below.

```
 Private Sub txtrownum_Change()

    'Here needs to be code where you can erase after it autocorrects,
    'the problem is when you try to erase it pulls up message box again and 
    'won't let you change it

    If txtrownum.Value > 100000 Then
        MsgBox "Maximum Number of Rows is 100,000"
        txtrownum.Value = "100000"
    End If
End Sub
```

However, once that 100,000 autofills, if the user wants to completely erase that value and enter a row number under 100,000, the Msgbox reappears and re-autofills with 100,000. If the user highlights 100,000, they can write over it no issue. But if they highlight "100,000" and presses backspace, the message reappears. Any advice?

Comment: try to use `Private Sub txtrownum_Exit(Cancel As Integer)` instead of `Private Sub txtrownum_Change()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking to see if the textbox value `isNumeric` first.

As @MathieuGuindon pointed out, it is better to first check if what the user input is a number, then do your additional check within that.

If it is not, then you can do additional steps in your `Else` section.

```
 Private Sub txtrownum_Change()
    'Here needs to be code where you can erase after it autocorrects,
    'the problem is when you try to erase it pulls up the message box again and
    'won't let you change it

    If IsNumeric(txtrownum.Value) Then

        'Now that we know it is a number, now we can do the check.
        If txtrownum.Value > 100000 Then
            MsgBox "Maximum Number of Rows is 100,000"
            txtrownum.Value = "100000"
        End If
    Else
        'do something if not a number
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can also just use `If Val(txtrownum.Value) > 100000`

Comment: Should work, but keep in mind that VBA conditionals don't short-circuit, so the `And txtrownum.Value > 100000` part still evaluates even when `IsNumeric(txtrownum.Vaule)` is `False`; arguably the `> 100000` check should only be done when the value is known to be numeric, i.e. the two conditions should be separated and nested.

Comment: And just for the sake of fun/why not, you could opt for a `KeyPress` event, to only accept numeric entry, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and) to prevent users to type non-numeric characters.

Comment: Works beautifully! Thank you all.