# Remove leading zeros from textbox VBA

Tags: excel, vba

User inputs only numerical values in textbox name `tbID`, in my file, that column value is saved as numerical. However, if user input `00120` instead of `120`. After attempting to remove the leading zeros, there seems to be a space before `120`.

When I input `Criteria1:="120"` it works

```
tbIDf = Cint(tbID) 'Debug.Print tbIDf gives " 120" and renders my filter criteria to a blank
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=IDN, Criteria1:="tbID"
```

How do I remove both the leading zeros and the `" "` in front of `120`?

Comment: Use `Trim()` to remove the space: [LTrim, RTrim, and Trim functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions)

Comment: I've tried LTrim(tbID) and the leading space is still there ):

Comment: what type of variable is `tbID`?

Comment: @Damian it was an input in the textbox that i forced to be `IsNumeric`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a thought, I would make sure data that makes it to your sheet is actually correct usable data. To do so you could use:

```
Trim(Val(tbID))
```

The use of [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) would return a double value ignoring non-numeric values, `120`. Alternatively [`CLng`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) is also a possibility returning a long value. Just don't use `CInt` as there is no need to use integers (range only from -32,768 to 32,767)

The [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ltrim-rtrim-and-trim-functions) function will remove leading and trailing spaces.

You can/should also implement a keypress event described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138833/making-vba-form-textbox-accept-numbers-only-including-and) to make sure only numerical values are entered.

[image]

Comment: Note that `Val` is a bit greedy and converts `"120auae"` to `120` too, while `CLng` and `CInt` would throw an error. Testing the input for numeric `IsNumeric("120auae")` would prevent this.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, yes, that's why I would prevent non-numeric input through keypress event linked in answer :)

Comment: I previously had a code on the textbox `IsNumeric` so only numbers can be input. have stuck with val(Me.tbID) and works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'just for testing (this comes from your textbox)
    Dim tbID As String
    tbID = "00120"

    If IsNumeric(tbID) Then 'test if numeric to prevent errors
        Dim MyCriteria As String
        MyCriteria = CStr(CLng(tbID))

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=IDN, Criteria1:=MyCriteria 
    End If
End Sub
```

If not use `Trim(CStr(CLng(tbID)))`